# selectInput not working

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("TEST", align = "center", style = "color:red")),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Marketing",sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("id",label = "Enter consultant Name"),
                   selectInput('s1','Select Names',choices = c('i','ij','ishu','ishan'),selected = NULL),
                   actionButton("a","Submit")
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput('out'),
        textOutput("sout")
      )
     )
    ),

    tabPanel("Recruitment",sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("id1",label = "Enter consultant Name"),
                   actionButton("a1","Submit")
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput('out1')
      )
     )
    ),

    tabPanel("Engineering",sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("id2",label = "Enter consultant Name"),
                   actionButton("a2","Submit")
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput('out2')
      )
     )
    ),

    tabPanel("Finance",sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("id3",label = "Enter consultant Name"),
                   actionButton("a3","Submit")
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput('out3')
      )
     )
    ),

    tabPanel("Legal",sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("id4",label = "Enter consultant Name"),
                   actionButton("a4","Submit")
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput('out4')
      )
     )
    ),

    tabPanel("Test",
        mainPanel(
        tableOutput('table')
      )       
     )  
  )
)
)
```

library(shiny)

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$a,
      output$out <- renderText(
                    input$id),
       output$sout <- renderText(input$s1)
     )

      observeEvent(input$a1,
                   output$out1 <- renderText(

                     input$id1
                   )
      )

      observeEvent(input$a2,
                   output$out2 <- renderText(

                     input$id2
                   )
      )

      observeEvent(input$a3,
                   output$out3 <- renderText(
                     input$id3
                   )
      )

      observeEvent(input$a4,
                   output$out4 <- renderText(
                     input$id4
                   )
      )
      output$table <- renderTable(read.csv('csv1.csv'))
    })
```

In this app I am trying to get names from selectInput function whenever user clicks on actionbutton with id "a". I am trying to do this under observeEvent() function but getting Error:- "Error in eval: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'". Please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in your server function. You need to enclose multi-line code within the `observeEvent` within `{}`. Just replace your code:

```
observeEvent(input$a,
      output$out <- renderText(
                    input$id),
       output$sout <- renderText(input$s1)
     )
```

with the following:

```
observeEvent(input$a,{
    output$out <- renderText(input$id)
    output$sout <- renderText(input$s1) 
  })
```

I think this would resolve the problem.

Hope it helps!